# spfx 3rd party javascript injecting iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, web-parts, spfx

I am creating a facebook webpart so I can wrap the settings.

When I have the following in my `render()`

```
this.domElement.innerHTML = `
  <div class="${styles.facebook}">
    <div class="${styles.container}">
      <div
        class="fb-page"
        data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ME/"
        data-tabs="timeline"
        data-height="300"
        data-small-header="false"
        data-adapt-container-width="true"
        data-hide-cover="false"
        data-show-facepile="true">
      <blockquote
        cite="https://www.facebook.com/ME/"
        class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ME/">Yes, its me again</a></blockquote></div>
  </div>
  </div>`;

this.facebook.XFBML.parse();
```

I get the following error

```
ErrorUtils caught an error: "Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a cross...". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.
```

I suspect the framework is not impressed with facebook injecting an `iframe`

If I load facebook as follows :

```
this.domElement.innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php.........
```

It works

I suppose, I could use the iframe approach and still inject my settings which are derived from properties.